# Hotmail contacts API

Tags: php, hotmail

I want to fetch all contacts email address from hotmail to my website using php to invite friends.
1.I found a hotmail contact api from:

http://livecontactsphp.codeplex.com/

but not working....just displaying the curl request url after authentication on my page.

My curl request url is:

```
$uri = "https://livecontacts.services.live.com/users/@C@".$output."/LiveContacts";
```

may be it has changed but i'm not getting correct url for that.

2.i tried openinviter:
http://openinviter.com/demo/
but only for hotmail it's saying invalid login for each email.

3.i also used php address importer but just for hotmail it is not working.

I've used many ways but not found any satisfactory result.
So is there any way by which i can access email address from hotmail either free/paid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft deprecated that API in mid-2012.

http://cloudsponge.com/news/2012/06/14/we-are-prepared-for-june-25-2012/

At this point the only supported method is to have your user export their contacts and upload the file to your site.

I'd love to hear your feedback on [CloudSponge](http://www.cloudsponge.com/test-drive).

If you like it, you can paste the widget HTML into your page and get it on your site in a few minutes.

We're working hard to be the best solution on the market for contact importing.

Disclaimer: I work for CloudSponge.